# Is linked text searchable by crawlers?

Tags: seo, javascript, keywords

I recently created a simple website for a web-app I made. The site and the app are both mobile oriented, so there is a limited amount of room for adding text content (I designed the interface to avoid page scrolling) for various web crawlers to pick up on.

As a solution, I want to create a small "link" that will render a dialog box with a site description. I'm new to SEO, so I'm not sure if it will work or if it's considered illegitimate practice. So, is what I described:

1) A legitimate way to add keywords to the site? (i.e. not 'keyword stuffing')

2) Searchable by web crawlers, even if the site description text only appears in the JavaScript?

3) If web crawlers don't "sniff" dynamic JavaScript-generated text, would it be a better idea to enter the text into the HTML directly, and make the link show/hide the element holding the text?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the consequences of all the options are, but I do know that the show/hide method works. This is because the text, if done right, can still be spidered by search engines and has not to date caused a penalty. You will see this technique on many sites that perform extremely well so I have to imagine this is the best option.